# Linux Sed command replace after special character

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How can I use sed command in Linux to replace key value pair. I want to replace characters that occur after “:”

For example
App.log.level: “xyz”

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want something like `sed 's/:.*$/: YOURTEXTHERE/'` where the general format is `sed 's/REPLACE_THIS/WITH_THIS/g'`

The `/:.*$/` bit means I want to replace all text from a colon to the end of the line.  The `: YOURTEXTHERE` is what you're replacing with. (I'm putting the colon back in and putting the extra text.) Since I'm only doing one replacement per line, I don't need the g at the end (although it wouldn't hurt anything.)

A real example:

```
>> echo App.log.level: \"xyz\" | sed 's/:.*$/: YOURTEXTHERE/'
App.log.level: YOURTEXTHERE
```

Comment: Awesome. I was exactly looking for something like that. Thank you so much